# About How to Create a Custom Text Box UI Using Python in Blender

Tags: python, units

I want to create a text box in Python to obtain the input text from the text box to provide data for my plugin, but I cannot find the function to create the text box. Currently, I can only create labels and buttons
What I want enter image description here to achieve is a text box that can input text, as shown in Figure 3

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [StringProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty)

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.prop(context.scene, 'input')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.input = bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Input')


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.input


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```